# Probability of two ranks next to each other in shuffled deck

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

What is the probability a jack is next to a 7 in a shuffled standard deck?

> I'm thinking there are 16 7/Jacks to pick from. We group an arbitrary one together which gives us 51 items. This gives us $16\times\frac{51!}{52!}$ or $4/13$

Comment: First consider a simpler problem with an 8-card deck that contains just the jacks and sevens, where your reasoning would yield a probability of $2$.

Comment: @RobPratt (for you and the original poster) : for what it's worth, I explored both Stars and Bars theory, and Inclusion-Exclusion-Theory, with this problem.  Personally, I found each method do-able, but a significant amount of trouble.  Hard to believe that this is an assigned homework problem.  Unless I am missing something, this one is no walk in the park.

Comment: To the OP (i.e. original poster).  This is not the time for guess-work.  The only way to reliably attack this problem is to stretch your intuition around some Combinatorics approach that you have already learned, and be very careful how you take each step.  Note that (for example) you can have the 7-Spades just before or just after the Jack-Spades.

Comment: You may want to consider finding the complementary probability, though keep in mind that jacks may be adjacent to each other and that sevens may be adjacent to each other.